# Re-sort get_posts query results

Tags: query, get-posts, sort

I have a query that pulls fields from the 3 most recent posts for a carousel:

```
get_posts('posts_per_page=3')
```

I need to re-order the results so that instead of it being

> 1, 2, 3

it is

> 3, 1, 2.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Reordering the way you want is really pretty trivial. Proof of concept:

```
$p = array(1,2,3);
var_dump($p);

array_push($p,array_shift($p));
var_dump($p);
```

With the WordPress code:

```
$p = get_posts('posts_per_page=3');
array_push($p,array_shift($p));
var_dump($p);
```

To make it more interesting, you can do the same with a filter. Since [`get_posts()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1839) uses `wp_query()` you can use the [`post_results`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3471) hook to reorder the results.

```
function post_shift_wpse_166761($p) {
  remove_filter('posts_results','post_shift_wpse_166761');
  array_push($p,array_shift($p));
  return $p;
}
add_filter('posts_results','post_shift_wpse_166761');

$p = get_posts(
  array(
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'posts_per_page' => 3
  )
);
var_dump(wp_list_pluck($p,'ID'));
```

Note that you also have to pass a `suppress_filters` argument to `get_posts()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think WordPress offers any way to order posts as you like. It has `ASC` and `DESC` order to list posts.

But you can create a custom field for each carousel post to define carousel item orders. Let's say if you created custom field named `carousel-order` and add numerical value to each post.

Then you can add custom order like this.

```
get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => '3',
        'meta_key' => 'carousel-order',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks - the trick is that the posts will be changing daily so

1 = most recent post
2 = second most recent post
3 = third most recent post

and I need to switch order so that it displays as: 

2 = second most recent post
3 = third most recent post
1 = most recent post


It would be cumbersome for the editors to keep updating the post order manually - so trying to find solution either using PHP or jQuery most likely.

Comment: `get_posts` returns an array, so you can dump it out in any order just using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your ideas. I ended up creating two different queries for the carousel re-ordering using offset:

The first query displays the third most recent post:

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'offset'=> 2 );
$thirdPost = get_posts( $args );
```

and then spit the required fields into the first carousel slide div.

The next query grabs the first and second most recent posts:

```
$args2 = array( 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'offset'=> 0 );
$firstPosts = get_posts( $args2 );
```

and then using "for each" spits the required fields into the second and third carousel slide div.